# Symfony validation not returning any violations for NotBlank

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

I'm using Symfony validation within my own app (not Symfony). I'm expecting it to return violations as I haven't populated the Id property:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setId('');
//...

$validator = \Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation::createValidator();
$errors = $validator->validate($user);
var_dump(count($errors)); exit; // outputs: 0
```

However, validate returns no violations.

Here is my User class with constraint annotations:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class User {

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $id;

    //...

    public function getId(): string {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(string $id): void {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    //...
```

Where am I going wrong? According to the docs, a blank string should trigger a violation for this constraint - https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Annotations if you use Validation.
Try this :

```
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$violations = $validator->validate($user->getId, [
    new NotBlank(),
]);
```

Comment: How would I have this work for multiple properties then? For example, getName(), getEmail(), etc. However, I prefer to use the annotations approach as it's neater. Can I not make it work with the annotations? Here uses a plain class but using annotations - https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: Check this out : https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html
Personnaly, i prefer this way. But, if you choose to use annotation, normally, you don't need validators. I don't know why it's don't work for your project.